# Guidance for making website compatible for different screensize

Tags: jquery, html, css, backbone.js, single-page-application

i am not a front end developer.i have to create a website.in which user has to submit a form.he asked different questions based on his previous answers.i searched on internet .i think single page website is a good thing because page is not reloading again and again so its a good user experience but my next goal is how to make appearance  website good for most of screen mobile,TV,Desktop,Tablets etc .please give some suggestions or points to remember for making site compatible for different platforms

Comment: You're talking about **Responsive Layout**. start with a desktop layout and mobile layout . Use tools like Twitter Bootstrap / jQuery Mobile to create responsive layout .

Comment: Which IDE will you be using to develop this SPA?